# How to remove <input> element inside another a list element?

Tags: jquery

How to remove `<input>` element inside another a list element? For example,

```
<li>
    <p>
        <input type='checkbox'></input>
        <strong>test number</strong>
        test information
    </p>
</li>
```

I only need to remove `<input></input>` and everything else remain the same.

Super Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Googling `jquery remove element` will yield a lot of hits; so will the "related" column to the right

Comment: Please don't sign your post. And what have you tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("li input").remove();
```

You may want to make your selectors more specific than that obviously.

More info on [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will do it for you :

```
$('li p > input').remove();
```

This will delete all input tags which are direct children of a p element which is within any li element.

Answer (score 1):

To remove an element from the DOM you can use [jQuery's](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) `.remove()` function.

Answer (score 1):

General selector for an `<input>` element inside a `<li>` element is `$('li input')`, then you just need to call the `.remove()` jQuery function to remove any matched elements from the DOM.